# how to avoid self inited API calls to Mobilefirst platform server V7.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mfp

I am frequently seeing the api call `"/worklight2/apps/services/api/*******/android/init" & "/worklight2/apps/services/api/******/android/query"` in MFP server logs(.../Iphone/init too). But i didn't see any of these API calls from my hybrid cordova mobile app. My question as below

1. Does it initiated from Mobilefirst?
2. Any purpose behind the calls?
3. How we can avoid this call temporary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call `/android/init` fires when you do a `WL.Client.connect()` API call from your client code. This can also happen if you have `{connectOnStartup : true}` in your wlInitOptions.js file.

`/android/query` occurs when you perform a `WL.Client.invokeProcedure()` from your client code.

These API calls are not initiated automatically from IBM MobileFirst client SDK. These have to be invoked.